# Perennial geranium collapses in late spring

Tags: plant-care, perennials

How can I care for this plant differently so it doesn't collapse in on itself? Do all geraniums fall in on themselves?

Every year these geraniums grow like crazy and get full, tall and beautiful like this...
[image: Perennial Geranium Max Frei]

... and then at some point it will rain and the whole plant collapses like a fallen cake and never really recovers.
[image: Fallen Perennial Geranium Max Frei]

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to tell which *Geranium* that is, other than it is a true cranesbill *Geranium*. Most *Geraniums* grow well in spring and early summer, but at some point, usually around June or July in the UK, the growth collapses outwards. At that point, it's usually possible to see new growth in the centre, small leaves appearing, and that is when you cut off  all the older growth, leaving only the central, new leaves growing. Varieties such as 'Wargrave's Pink' will then grow on and re-flower in the same season, but there are others that only flower early in the year, so the new growth, whilst looking tidy as it grows, does not produce further flowers. Heavy torrential rain might mean the plant gets smashed to the ground, but otherwise, look for the new growth, or at least to see if there is any, next time the plant collapses outwards.